# Is there some sort of system-wide font replacement table in Linux?

Tags: fonts, fontconfig

I have a problem with the **Arial** font that I have installed together with Wine. It's causing a strange behavior while editing annotations in the Linux version of Foxit PDF Reader. If I remove this font, I then experience problems in the display of some websites (e.g. DistroWatch) under Firefox.

There is a very useful **font replacement table in LibreOffice options** for such purposes. So I wonder if there's a similar way doing this system-wide in Linux - e.g. telling the system and all apps to use say DejaVu Sans for Arial.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font_configuration#Replace_or_set_default_fonts

Comment: @contemplator Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed! Out of the two options there, the first one did't work but the second did (removing Arial font, and preferring Noto Sans instead) under Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon. If you like you can simply copy and paste that section to earn points ;-)

Comment: For the record, I've also discovered that my system tries to use the closest match to Arial when it's not available, and the problem with some websites in Firefox was that the closest match found was "Arial Black" (not a good choice!). When I removed it, the system then began using "Arial Narrow" (which wasn't a good match either). It eventually found a good alternative (I'm not sure which, maybe Noto Sans, but a good match for sure) after I also removed it. In the end, I really didn't need that font replacement table.